При добавлении Яндекс карты через iframe выходит ошибка passive
Добавляю карту через iframe в html, пробовала и через js.
Но ошибки присутствуют в двух случаях
Подскажите в чем проблема и как это решить


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Вопросы, которые не стоит задавать: => Поиск ошибок, которые нельзя воспроизвести => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic //как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Пожалуйста, пришлите код или ссылку на страницу, где можно воспроизвести ситуацию. Карта не работает совсем? Сообщения появляются только в Chrome?

Это не ошибки, это уведомления, на работоспособность они не влияют.
